# Javascript modals so slow when I parse EE content into them

Tags: javascript

I have a small simple site that is one index page with four popup modals. Everything works fine on the iphone until I try to parse EE content into them. This is the first bit of EE content I am pulling into the site:

{exp:channel:entries channel="about" disable="categories|member_data|pagination"}

{about}

{/exp:channel:entries}

Once i do this it slows down so much that the site is unusable on the iphone...

Whats going on? I am just pulling in text? Is it something to do with the way its loading? The modals are controlled by javascript.

When I load the content outside of the modals it loads quickly and is ok. The modals load okay on their on desktop only on iphone) - how can I fix this? I have enable caching, but its not doing anything....

This is not good! Please help!

Comment: What Overlay plugin are you using? Are your mobile templates different from your desktop templates? Have you tried disabling the EE caching? Have you tried on different phones? Could be a network issue with your provider. Do you have a URL where we can see the issue?

Comment: I thought it was the single entry plugin, but I have now realised that there is something happening with any entry from my "about" channel.... other channels are loading fine?

Comment: UPdate: Any channel that has matrix fields is showing this slow behaviour.

Comment: Are there very large images in these Matrix fields? If so, reduce the size. Are you using an addon like CE Image to resize the images? Perhaps there is an error specific to CE Cache storing the resized image.

Comment: Also, make sure you are using the newest Matrix version.

Answer (score 1):

These aren't the issues obviously but I'd change two things in your code.

1. Add "category_fields" to your disable="" parameter:

   `disable="categories|member_data|pagination|category_fields"`
2. If there is only one entry for "About", then call the entry with the `entry_id=""` parameter.

---

Next, I'd look at trying another overlay plugin to see if it's an issue with the one you are using.

Comment: Just a note that disabling `category_fields` is redundant - if you're disabling `categories` it's already included in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Dependant on the mechanism that fires ur modal, include the modal contents inside a hidden div on the page and refer to its #id, gets the rendering done on page load and makes the modal appear snappier.

Comment: Im using jquery.bpopup

Comment: what I have worked out is that anything that takes a bit more processing (matrix or conditionals, twitter javascript feed) are causing that modal to load too slowly, and its freezing up on the iphone. The site is at www.staccatotunes.com/testsite12

I thought that with jquery bpopup that the content inside the modals would be loading when the whole index page loads, - is that not the case? Does it only load when you click? I though it just unhid the div?

Comment: Problem solving begins with stripping everything back to basics. By having the page load the file you can then gauge if its a server thing or modal thing.

Comment: I just stripped everything back and have been very painfully re-adding code line by line, it was all working okay until I added in a matrix field. 

It wont let me do matrix or conditionals without causing the load issue. 
 Im considering getting this Solspace addon Static Page Caching - do you think that will fix problem?  
From reading what it says on the site, Im hoping it will go through the template and pull all the data and have it sitting static, ready to go thus eliminating the load time problem....

Comment: If ur code isn't changing that much, I'd look at stash, it has some good caching methods & its free :-)